# Trouble extracting request data in Node.js (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to extract data from a request (in this case a `POST`) and am having trouble. I'm doing so using the `body-parser` module. Below is a portion of my code (note I am using ES6 syntax):

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlEncoded({extended: true})

app.post('*', setFileMeta, setDirDetails, urlEncodedParser, (req, res, next) => {
    async ()=> {
        if (!req.stat) return res.send(405, 'File does not exist')
        if (req.isDir) return res.send(405, 'Path is a directory') // This is an advanced case

        await fs.promise.truncate(req.filePath, 0)
        req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(req.filePath)) // Filepath is a file

        // This below line is where I need the body
        sendToClients('update', req.url, 'file', req.body, Date.now())

        res.end()
    }().catch(next)
})
```

For the actual extraction of the data using `body-parser`, `urlEncoded` is the only way I was able to successfully do it (the data is just a string for now), and it's giving me in the format `{content: ''}` where content is the actual string I'm using. This isn't ideal but it works in this simple. However, this is breaking the `createWriteStream(req.filePath)` as seen above - the file is created, but there is no content.

There must be something obvious that I'm doing incorrectly, as I'm new to Node and Express. Since I wrote the majority of this with the help of an instructional video, my gut tells me it's the body extraction part since I'm doing that on my own.

Comment: isnt await/async es7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body-parser` exhausts (fully reads) the request stream in order to parse the incoming parameters, so there's no data left in the request stream to write to your file.

It seems to me that you're trying to implement file uploads. In that case, you probably want to use a module like [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) instead of `body-parser`.

Comment: I was effectively trying to create a Dropbox clone - using TCP to send create/update/delete commands to listening clients. What I ended up doing was creating a middleware using `body-parser` to read the body and store it on the request, and then when writing the file, using `fs.createWriteStream` and then `fs.write` using the body that was read with `body-parser`. I still have the issue of only being able to read the string off the body as a key in a JSON object, but for simple strings, I've got it working.